# How to translate the library in Angular without initializing Translation service in app?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, shared-libraries, ngx-translate

I have a library file named 'controls' and this library file is used by various other apps. I am using ngx-translate for translation purpose. Some of the apps using this library perform translation and some do not. I want my library to be self sufficient and load by default the English language without initializing the translation service in the app.

My json files are in the folder: projects->controls->src->shared->assets->i18n.

I have written the following code in controls.module.ts but the app is not finding the json file and hence not able to load the translations.

```
    export function HttpLoaderFactory(handler:HttpBackend) {
        const http = new HttpClient(handler);
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'projects/controls/src/shared/assets/i18n/','.json');
    }

    @NgModule({
    imports: [
       ......
       HttpClientModule,
       TranslateModule.forRoot({
         isolate: true,
         loader: {
         provide: TranslateLoader,
         useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
         deps:[HttpBackend],
         }
       }),
      .......]
    exports:[ ....
      TranslateModule]
   })

    export class ControlsModule {
      constructor(private translate:TranslateService) {
         this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The path in TranslateHttpLoader() is probably incorrect. When you are running `ng serve`, the translations file should be accessible on the browser using the path that you are specifying here. If the file is accessible at `http://localhost:<PORT>/shared/assets/i18n/en.json`, then try the following -

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './shared/assets/i18n/');
}
```

Also, you can set the default language when importing the module.

```
imports: [
  ...
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  },
  defaultLanguage: 'en'
 })
]
```